# Can't find Jms queue created by annotation in Glassfish 4

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms, jndi

I am learning the book Java EE essentials and I'working on its end to end sample app. The app uses a JMS queue as shown below:

```
@JMSDestinationDefinition(name = "java:global/jms/pointsQueue",
    interfaceName = "javax.jms.Queue")
```

The code works and the corresponding queue is created and the messaging is working but I can't find it in JNDI Resources on **Glassfish 4** admin console. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

The resources you create using @JMSDestinationDefinition is only visible for the application in which it is created